# How to iterate through multiple tables in azure databricks data and delete the matching record in postgres database?

Tags: sql, postgresql, azure-databricks

I am extracting data from azure databricks table and loading only the first row (rank = 1) into similar table(same table structure) in postgres. However before loading, I'm checking if the column5 value in postgres table is same as the databricks table, if yes, then that row has to be deleted from postgres table and the remaining values have to be loaded.

Here I want to iterate over the rows of my extracted databricks table and run delete command for each row in postgres. Please suggest a way to achieve this in SQL without using cursors ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a staging table `stg`.

Load it from the databricks table. Ideally , export from databricks using:

`SELECT * FROM databricks_table WHERE rank_column = 1 -- or WHERE RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY whatever ORDER BY whatever_else) = 1`

Then, on PostgreSQL, use the MERGE statement:

```
MERGE INTO tgt USING stg ON tgt.column5 = stg.column5
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
  col1 = stg.col1
, col2 = stg.col2
[. . .]
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (col1,col2, ... , coln)
                      VALUES(stg.col1,stg.col2 ...)
;
```

Check the PostgreSQL docu for the MERGE statement for more details ...